# R: Defining a function in R including a for loop and if condition

Tags: r, function, for-loop

let's consider for example the following vector in R: `x <- 2*c(1:100)`.

Now I want to define a stepwise function which should attain the value `x[1] = 2` for x if `x >= 0 & x < 1`´, the `x[2] = 4` for x if `x >= 1 & x < 2`´....

```
I tried to do this with the following code:

y <- 2*c(1:100)

f <- function(x){for(i in 1:100){if((x >= i-1) & (x < i)){y[i]}
                                }
                }
```

This didn't work - what is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can u show the expected output

Comment: Apart from the syntax error of a missing paranthesis at the end of ( x< i ), the if must have only one TRUE or FALSE output, but you have a vectorized boolean that executes for all values in x, so the function can't decide on which value to use (in these cases, it will use the first one)

Comment: Ok - so how would u define a stepwise function then? (in this case as an example from 1:100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you miss a closing bracket  in `if` condition. It should be like this:

```
if((x >= i-1) & (x < i))
```

Second of all, your function uses `x` as an argument as well as an external vector's name. That's confusing.

Third of all,

```
function(y) x[floor(y)]
```

would be more efficient